# Is it reasonable to convert factor (only 0/1 involved) into numeric data?

Tags: classification, clustering, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

If I have a simple data with only 2 levels of factors:

```
           Dog Cat Bird Frog Rabbit Monkey Male 
unknown.1   1   0    0   0     0      0      1        
unknown.2   1   0    0   0     0      0      0      
unknown.3   0   1    0   0     0      0      1      
unknown.4   0   0    0   0     1      0      1
```

and I want to do classification(clustering) on this, can I safely convert the 0/1 factors into numeric 0,1 ?

Comment: Most likely this conversion has already been done.

Comment: @whuber I test them with `class()` and they have a class factor, wondering if I can convert them to numeric using `as.numeric()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your 0/1 variables (except the last one `Male`) really are the levels of a categorical variable `Species` already coded. You can use them as is, but note that they will sum to one, so you need to leave one out if used in a regression-like model.

As for the last one `Male`, a binary variable coded as numerical 0/1 is exactly the same as you get if you code it as a factor, and let your software do the representation. Before using a variable in a regression model, it must somehow be coded as numerical. It doesn't matter if you or the software does the conversion.